# Drupal, Views module, Group fields in layout

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I want to group some fields inside a div or similar HTML tag, for example I'm displaying node's title + node's teaser + node's image, I want to group the title and teaser into one DIV in layout for easier CSS styling.

I know a silly method to do it in templates, but I want a quicker and easier method (Drag-and-drop in views edit). A similar example is CCK Fieldgroup.

Answer (score 0):

semanticviews can do it http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews. You can customize html output and group field from the views interface.

You can also group the Field with CCK and dipslay the node instead of field.

Or using node.tpl.php to chose exactly witch field you want to show and how.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a sandbox project I have used before for grouping views fields into columns at [edward_or's sandbox](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/eoriordan/1241454). I have found this the simplest to use of all the modules.